# Can someone suggest a way to do this query using Doctrine (QueryBuilder) with multiple "where" clause?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I'm new to the QueryBuilder and I'm trying to do a POST request (with a JSON) to retrieve some informations in my database.

I'm using array because each property can have several values. Here's the JSON I'm currently sending :

```json
{
    "name":["Martin"],
    "state":["Ohio", "Texas"],
    "job":["Photographer", "Reporter"]
}
```

Here's my database :

```
ID  |   NAME        |   FIRST_NAME  |   STATE       |   JOB             |   SPEAK_FRENCH
1   |   Martin      |   John        |   Ohio        |   Photographer    |   1
2   |   Martin      |   Max         |   Ohio        |   Reporter        |   1
3   |   Martin      |   Sophie      |   Texas       |   Model           |   1
4   |   Alexander   |   David       |   Kansas      |   Author          |   0
5   |   Archie      |   Kira        |   Maine       |   Photographer    |   1
6   |   Lushen      |   Albert      |   Nevada      |   Pilot, Model    |   1
7   |   Wilkins     |   Minnie      |   Utah        |   Tailor          |   0
8   |   Martin      |   Thomas      |   Texas       |   Reporter        |   1
9   |   Patino      |   Stephen     |   Virginia    |   Pilot, Reporter |   1
10  |   Ting        |   Maria       |   Nevada      |   Dentist         |   0
11  |   Brown       |   Barbara     |   Virginia    |   Reporter        |   1
12  |   Martin      |   William     |   Texas       |   Photographer    |   1
13  |   Zachary     |   Thomas      |   Virginia    |   Telephonist     |   1
```

The request I would like to have :

```sql
SELECT * FROM 'application'
WHERE SPEAK_FRENCH = 1
AND NAME = "Martin"
AND STATE = "Ohio"
AND JOB LIKE "%Photographer%"
OR SPEAK_FRENCH = 1
AND NAME = "Martin"
AND STATE = "Ohio"
AND JOB LIKE "%Reporter%"
OR SPEAK_FRENCH = 1
AND NAME = "Martin"
AND STATE = "Texas"
AND JOB LIKE "%Photographer%"
OR SPEAK_FRENCH = 1
AND NAME = "Martin"
AND STATE = "Texas"
AND JOB LIKE "%Reporter%"
```

And what I have currently done in Symfony, doesn't work the way I want it to :

```php
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Application::class);
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('request');
$temp_name = 0;
$temp_state = 0;
$temp_job = 0;
foreach ($app->getName() as $name) {
    $temp_name = $temp_name + 1;

    $query = $query->orWhere('request.speakFrench = 1')
        ->andWhere('request.name LIKE :JSONname' . strval($temp_name))
        ->setParameter('JSONname' . strval($temp_name), $name);

    foreach ($app->getState() as $state) {
        $temp_state = $temp_state + 1;

        $query = $query->andWhere('request.state LIKE :JSONstate' . strval($temp_state))
            ->setParameter('JSONstate' . strval($temp_state), $state);

        foreach ($app->getJob() as $job) {
        $temp_job = $temp_job + 1;

        $query = $query->andWhere('request.job LIKE :JSONjob' . strval($temp_job))
            ->setParameter('JSONjob' . strval($temp_job), '%' . $job . '%');
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to get this result :

```
ID  |   NAME        |   FIRST_NAME  |   STATE       |   JOB             |   SPEAK_FRENCH
1   |   Martin      |   John        |   Ohio        |   Photographer    |   1
2   |   Martin      |   Max         |   Ohio        |   Reporter        |   1
8   |   Martin      |   Thomas      |   Texas       |   Reporter        |   1
12  |   Martin      |   William     |   Texas       |   Photographer    |   1
```

My code isn't working well, it doesn't send any error but only return `ID : 8`.

I'm looking for a way to do the query that returns only the `ID : 1, 2, 8 and 12`.

Thanks a lot for your future answers.

P.S : I'm running Symfony 4.3.11.

Comment: @Strawberry I would like to have a fully functionnal query that really work the way I want (return id 1, 2, 8 and 12). 
The code I posted in PHP return only the "last" query, like I have sent this json : 

`{   "name":["Martin"],   "state":["Texas"],   "job":["Reporter"]  }`

Comment: If speed is what you need, building a raw sql string from your json fields would be the answer. If simplicity is what you want I sometimes do something like `->where('request.name LIKE "%theName%"')->andWhere('request.job = "job1" OR request.job = "job2'')` and so one. It would be different in your case but maybe I gave you some ideas.

Comment: I may be missing some subtle point here but I don't understand why the IN operator would not work for you:  WHERE name IN (:names) AND state IN (:states) etc.  DQL is nice in that it can handle array parameters for IN operators.

Comment: @MartinM. I think I'll certainly use something like that yeah, thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, I rarely need to use `IN` so I forgot but Cerad is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Doctrine you can do for exemple:

```
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('request');
    $queryBuilder
        ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('user.speakFrench', ':speakFrench'),
            $queryBuilder->expr()->like('request.name', ':name'),
            $queryBuilder->expr()->in('request.state', ':states'),
            $queryBuilder->expr()->in('request.job', ':jobs'),
        ))
        ->setParameter('speakFrench', true)
        ->setParameter('name', 'Martin')
        ->setParameter('states', ['Ohio', 'Texas'])
        ->setParameter('jobs', ['Photographer', 'Reporter'])
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

That should be a good start.

**To continue:**

- Many examples of Doctrine usage: [Hot examples](https://hotexamples.com/examples/doctrine.orm/QueryBuilder/expr/php-querybuilder-expr-method-examples.html)
- Check Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr class, there's a lot of useful functions. [Doctrine Expr GitHub](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.7/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr.php)
- Check the documentation that provides many examples: [Doctrine Query Builder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html#working-with-querybuilder)

Comment: Thanks, gonna help me for sure !

Answer (score 0):

The following would appear to be a valid query corresponding to your requirements:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM application
 WHERE SPEAK_FRENCH = 1
    AND NAME = "Martin"
    AND STATE = IN("Ohio","Texas")
    AND (JOB LIKE "%Photographer%" OR JOB LIKE "%Reporter%");
```

Also, see [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: It helps me, thanks. Does this works the same way if I have multiple names ?

Do you have any ideas on how to do it using Doctrine QueryBuilder ?

Comment: Normalise your schema. Then you can use IN() (and indexes) for all the conditions.